# Indigo on trusty: how to handle ffmpeg dependency

Tags: rosdep, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My project depends on libavcodec-dev, libavformat-dev, libavutil-dev, libswscale-dev.
To this end for groovy and hydro in package.xml  I added a build and run dependency on ffmpeg
that brings from rosdep the expected dependencies:

In https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml there is:

```
ffmpeg:
  arch: [ffmpeg]
  debian: [ffmpeg, libavcodec-dev, libavformat-dev, libavutil-dev, libswscale-dev]
  fedora: [ffmpeg-devel]
  gentoo:
    portage:
      packages: [media-plugins/ffmpeg]
  macports: [ffmpeg]
  ubuntu: [ffmpeg, libavcodec-dev, libavformat-dev, libavutil-dev, libswscale-dev]
```

Now for indigo it seems that the ffmpeg debian package is not available for trusty.

We cannot change rosdep/base.yaml to the following (even if it shall work for trusty):

```
  debian: [libavcodec-dev, libavformat-dev, libavutil-dev, libswscale-dev]
  ubuntu: [libavcodec-dev, libavformat-dev, libavutil-dev, libswscale-dev]
```

Shall I introduce new entries for each debian package ?

```
libavcodec-dev:
  debian: [libavcodec-dev]
  ubuntu: [libavcodec-dev]

libavformat-dev:
  debian: [libavformat-dev]
  ubuntu: [libavformat-dev]

libavutil-dev:
  debian: [libavutil-dev]
  ubuntu: [libavutil-dev]

libswscale-dev:
  debian: [libswscale-dev]
  ubuntu: [libswscale-dev]
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Fabien

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147081/indigo-on-trusty:-how-to-handle-ffmpeg-dependency/) by [Fabien Spindler](https://answers.ros.org/users/3990/fabien-spindler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like ffmpeg has been deprecated in Ubuntu for a while, and it's being replaced in 14.04 with lbav-tools according to http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04 .

You should probably either:

- declare a new rosdep called `avtools` or similar, which contains most of the same things that ffmpeg contained. This may introduce extra maintenance for packages that will have to switch their API to depending on avtools.
- update the existing ffmpeg dependency to silently depend on avtools on newer versions of Ubuntu. This will probably become very brittle as the avtools and ffmpeg command-line tools and APIs diverge in upcoming Ubuntu releases.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1